# Valence Role Settings

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I'm trying to retrieve the Course Access Options ("Access inactive courses", "Access past courses" and "Access future courses" specifically) of the roles within my instance of BrightSpace using Valence, and I haven't been able to figure out how.

I've looked at /d2l/api/lp/(version)/roles/, to no avail, and no other API called jumps out at me as being useful for this.

Is this just something that isn't currently possible to do with Valence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the Brightspace APIs don't provide access to course-access settings for roles, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Permissions](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/permissions.html) routes. Since permissions are assigned to roles, there is a  [route](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/permissions.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28version%29-permissions-tools-%28toolId%29-capabilities-) you can use to query permissions claims by tool, as well as a [route](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/permissions.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28version%29-permissions-tools-%28toolId%29-claims-) that you can pass roles as parameters to limit to permissions available to that role. I haven't experimented with these myself yet, so I cannot

Comment: So unfortunately those only allow you to deal with permissions of the various roles.  The three values I'm looking for are settings, not permissions, and so none of those routes work (also they are listed as unstable so I'd rahter not sure them evne if they did provide me with what I needed).